# How to check the temp.info value is 0 or 1 or true false

Tags: typoscript

I am facing issue in tyopscript to check the true false condition for the `temp.info` variable.
From below function I am getting 0 or 1 from the function -

```
temp.info = USER_INT
temp.info {
    userFunc = tx_gowebsso_pi1->excludeMenu
    includeLibs = EXT:gowebsso/pi1/class.tx_gowebsso_pi1.php
}
```

I am printing this value and getting correct

but when I try to check it like

```
[temp.info = 1]
```

or

```
[temp.info = 0]
```

It's not going into the conditions. I tried all the ways.
Please help me how I can set conditions in typoscript.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this condition: [userFunc = yourFuncName(argument)]

But you have to edit your configuration-file to register your function. Please read more about userFunc and conditions in the [manual](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#condition-userfunc).

**Another way to check if an userFunc returns true or false and print different content on each state:**

Using a php-file located in fileadmin/php/myUserfunc.php. checkSomeThing() returns a value. In this case it is 1.

```
<?php
    class user_myFuncs {
        function checkSomeThing ($content, $conf){
            $content = 1;
            return $content;
        }
    }
?>
```

You can print different contents on true and false like this:

```
page >
includeLibs.truefalse = fileadmin/php/myUserfunc.php
page = PAGE
page {
  10 = TEXT
  10 {
    value = Show this, if checkSomeThing () returns something which is true

    if.isTrue.postUserFunc = user_myFuncs->checkSomeThing
  }

  20 = TEXT
  20 {
    value = Show this, if checkSomeThing () returns something which is false

    if.isTrue.postUserFunc = user_myFuncs->checkSomeThing
    if.negate = 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ..I already have conditions in the excludeMenu in which i am checking cookies are set or not for the user if set then i am returning true and if not then returning 0 ..so in temp.info i am getting the value 0 or 1.. and in typoscript i want to check condition [temp.info = 1] or [temp.info = 0] but its not works.. do you know how i can set it..

Comment: Hi let me explain what need to do it on them temp.info conditions...
if temp.info is 1 i need to exclude the menu id from the hmenu and if not then it will as it is
[temp.info = 1]
lib.mainNavigation.excludeUidList.cObject = TEXT
lib.mainNavigation.excludeUidList.cObject.value = 18
[else]
lib.mainNavigation.excludeUidList.cObject = TEXT
lib.mainNavigation.excludeUidList.cObject.value = 
[global]

Comment: Hi Christian thanks for your time i found another way to hide the menu in typoscript. I am checking some conditions in plugin when plugin loads and then i am setting a cookie for it and i am checking that cookie in typoscript